# Internet Explorer - Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce514

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

The following code works in chrome and in firefox, but gives the error "Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce514". I googled it, and found that it has something to do with setting the proper character set encoding, but I am loading an image with this (the url would end up being something like http://www.mysite.com/images/this_image.jpg). How do I get this to work in IE?

```
var originalSRC = $("#bigImage").attr("src");
$(".tinyThumb").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#oiLoad").html('<img src="http://mysite.com/images/oiload.gif">');
    var oldSRC = $(this).attr("src");
    var newSRC = "http://"+window.location.host+oldSRC.replace("tiny_thumbs/xtn_",""); 
    $("#bigImage").load(newSRC,function(e){
            $("#oiLoad").empty();
              $("#bigImage").attr("src",newSRC);
    });

});
```

Comment: Not realy an answer but I did notice you are not closing your img tag.
$("#oiLoad").html('<img src="http://mysite.com/images/oiload.gif">');
Should be 
$("#oiLoad").html('<img src="http://mysite.com/images/oiload.gif" />');

Comment: @Agile: Actually, that is the answer.  IE will choke om that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not realy an answer but I did notice you are not closing your img tag.

```
$("#oiLoad").html('<img src="mysite.com/images/oiload.gif">');
```

Should be closed with a backslash

Answer (score 1):

As [Agile Jedi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/550288/agile-jedi) said, you need to close the `<img />` tag.